# How can I hide automatic x axis title in plotly to set my own, updating is also an option

Tags: python, plotly, boxplot, axis-labels, x-axis

I want to set a fitting x and y axis name on my px. box() graph, the problème is that the automatic name doesn't disappear:

```
fig1 = px.box(birth_price_box1["price"],
             log_x=False,
             color = birth_price_box1["birth"])

fig1.update_traces(hoverinfo='skip', 
                  hovertemplate = None
                 )

fig1.update_layout(
    title={
        'text': "montant total des achats en fonction de l'année de naissance",
        'y':0.95,
        'x':0.5,
        'xanchor': 'center',
        'yanchor': 'top'
    },
    
    xaxis_title = "année",
    yaxis_title = "montant total (€)",
)

fig1.show()
```

the result : [boxplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbTJt.png)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Building on [this example](https://plotly.com/python/box-plots/#choosing-the-algorithm-for-computing-quartiles), you can just include:

```
fig.update_xaxes(title_text = 'New x-axis title')
```

Or in your specifc example, replace:

```
xaxis_title =  "année"
```

with:

```
xaxis_title_text =  "année"
```

#### Plot

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.tips()

fig = px.box(df, x="day", y="total_bill", color="smoker")
fig.update_traces(quartilemethod="exclusive") # or "inclusive", or "linear" by default
f = fig.full_figure_for_development(warn=False)

fig.update_xaxes(title_text = 'New x-axis title')
fig.show()
```

Comment: Thanks vestland, I tried but doesn't seem to work, but using your way to call the graph:

px. box(df, x="day", y="total_bill", color="smoker") 
and not 
px.box (df["day"], color=df["smoker"])

Everything seems to work properly

Comment: @CorentinMetral `fig.update_xaxes(title_text = 'New x-axis title')``should work either way. If it doesn't,, then there's something funky about the way you've set up the figure. In either case, do you have what you need now?

Comment: sorry I'm steel not familiar with notif of stack overflow and didn't see your reply all good, I got what I needed thanks a lot.